# Writing string values using tcpclient in Matlab

Tags: matlab, tcp

I am trying to send a matrix of strings from my Matlab client to a server (i.e. ['Hello', 'World']). I am using Matlab's tcpclient (because it comes for free, unlike the tcpip tool). Looking at the documentation for writing to a server using tcpclient (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tcpclient.write.html#inputarg_data), it appears that I can only write data if it is a 1xN matrix of numeric data.

Is there a different method by which I can write this string matrix to the server, and avoid buying the Instrument Control toolbox for tcpip?

Comment: By string I assume you mean an array of ASCII characters. You can map these to `uint8` very straightforwardly and then uncap them on the server.